# how to make a multi delete query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hello people i have a question about this query;

```
DELETE FROM 
 our_work, 
 our_work_images, 
 our_work_portf_img
WHERE 
 our_work.id = 6
AND 
 our_work_portf_img.portf_id = 6
AND
 our_work_portf_img.img_id = our_work_images.img_id;
```

i want to delete all relations from the first table "our_work" my pair table is named "our_wrok_porft_img" and my image table "our_work_images"

EDIT;

I solved the problem by adding cascade on the foreign key

`DELETE FROM our_work WHERE our_work.id = 1;`

Comment: Implicit joins are discourage..

Comment: If you want to delete all relations from `our_work` just remove foreign key `constraints` with tables you mentioned. Your question seems to be different from what your code shows.

Comment: @ConsiderMe it's not jet the answer i was hoping to get, are there other ways for doing the same?

Comment: Can you show us the create table statements? Are there foreign keys involved?

Comment: i don't have the option to add images at stackoverflow so i guess i can't show u @AaronKent

Comment: yes there are foreign keys involved. how could i otherwise add a cascade...

Comment: We don't need images. Just run some `CREATE TABLE` statements and share the output.

Comment: i dont need any help on this toppic anymore @AaronKent but thanks